# Can I get a notification if clock changed/adjusted?

Tags: java, clock

I have a program which relies on the clock-time to do some recurring tasks. How can I tell that clock was changed and I need to re-adjust my tasks?

**EDIT**: I am using a `Date` instance to see if time already passed or not.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by clock time?

Comment: What kind of changes? Are you worried about timezone changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start a new thread which:

1. Fetches the current clock time and stores it in a variable V
2. Sleeps for X milliseconds
3. Adds X to V, compares it to the current clock time
4. If the values don't match to within a few milliseconds, assume the clock has changed, and trigger a reschedule
5. Rinse and repeat

Comment: is there also JAVA api to get a notification?

Comment: @ohadshai: Not to my knowledge, no.

Comment: @ohadshai "is there also JAVA api to get a notification?"  You expect an API for something that could be achieved in a few lines of code?!?  Sheesh.. kids today.

Comment: This approach would fail in some edge casses, E.g. if CPU is busy thread might sleep for more than specified interval, or if system goes into hibernate, thread might be sleeping overnight. In both casses this method would assume that time has changed.

Comment: @Shamit: true, but it doesn't need to be fool-proof, all the OP wanted was a way to know if his tasks should be rescheduled. if it fails occasionally, no harm done.

Comment: @skaffman: one problem with that approach is that if clock was modified, and then went back to the original time while the checking thread was sleeping, it will not notice such change.

Comment: @ohadshai: Does it matter, then? You can always just reduce the sleep period.